# error when adding gx_file_picker to a picker sheet in flutter app

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

hello I am working on a app that lets users upload audio from their devices to a account profile. I am getting a error when trying to create the upload audio action card.
here is the error I'm getting:

> Positional arguments must occur before named arguments.  Try moving
> all of the positional arguments before the named arguments. Too many
> positional arguments: 0 expected, but 2 found.  Try removing the extra
> positional arguments, or specifying the name for named arguments. Open
> documentation

the error is on this line of code:

File file;

here is the code I have for the profile page:

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:gx_file_picker/gx_file_picker.dart';
import 'package:mix/model/MessageData.dart';
import 'package:mix/model/User.dart';
import 'package:mix/services/FirebaseHelper.dart';
import 'package:mix/services/helper.dart';
import 'package:mix/ui/accountDetails/AccountDetailsScreen.dart';
import 'package:mix/ui/auth/AuthScreen.dart';
import 'package:mix/ui/contactUs/ContactUsScreen.dart';
import 'package:mix/ui/fullScreenImageViewer/FullScreenImageViewer.dart';
import 'package:mix/ui/settings/SettingsScreen.dart';
import 'package:mix/ui/upgradeAccount/UpgradeAccount.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:page_view_indicators/circle_page_indicator.dart';

import '../../constants.dart';
import '../../main.dart';

class ProfileScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final User user;


  ProfileScreen({Key key, @required this.user}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ProfileScreenState createState() => _ProfileScreenState(user);
}

class _ProfileScreenState extends State<ProfileScreen> {
  final ImagePicker _imagePicker = ImagePicker();
  User user;

  FireStoreUtils _fireStoreUtils = FireStoreUtils();
  final _currentPageNotifier = ValueNotifier<int>(0);

  _ProfileScreenState(this.user);

  List images = List();
  List _pages = [];
  List<Widget> _gridPages = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    images.clear();
    images.addAll(user.photos);
    if (images.isNotEmpty) {
      if (images[images.length - 1] != null) {
        images.add(null);
      }
    } else {
      images.add(null);
    }
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _gridPages = _buildGridView();
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: <
            Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0, left: 32, right: 32),
            child: Stack(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              children: <Widget>[
                Center(
                    child:
                        displayCircleImage(user.profilePictureURL, 130, false)),
                Positioned(
                  left: 80,
                  right: 0,
                  child: FloatingActionButton(
                      backgroundColor: Color(COLOR_ACCENT),
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.camera_alt,
                        color:
                            isDarkMode(context) ? Colors.black : Colors.white,
                      ),
                      mini: true,
                      onPressed: _onCameraClick),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0, right: 32, left: 32),
            child: SizedBox(
              width: double.infinity,
              child: Text(
                user.fullName(),
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: isDarkMode(context) ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
                    fontSize: 20),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ),
          ),




          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0, left: 16, right: 16),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: skipNulls([
                Text(
                  'My Music',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                _pages.length >= 2
                    ? CirclePageIndicator(
                  selectedDotColor: Color(COLOR_ACCENT),
                  dotColor: Colors.grey,
                  itemCount: _pages.length,
                  currentPageNotifier: _currentPageNotifier,
                )
                    : null
              ]),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16, bottom: 8),
            child: SizedBox(
                height: user.photos.length > 3 ? 260 : 130,
                width: double.infinity,
                child: PageView(
                  children: _gridPages,
                  onPageChanged: (int index) {
                    _currentPageNotifier.value = index;
                  },
                )),
          ),
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              ListTile(
                dense: true,
                onTap: () {
                  push(context, new AccountDetailsScreen(user: user));
                },
                title: Text(
                  'Account Details',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                ),
                leading: Icon(
                  Icons.person,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
              ),
              ListTile(
                dense: true,
                onTap: () {
                  showModalBottomSheet(
                    isScrollControlled: true,
                    context: context,
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
                        top: Radius.circular(20),
                      ),
                    ),
                    builder: (context) {
                      return UpgradeAccount();
                    },
                  );
                },
                title: Text(
                  user.isVip != null && user.isVip
                      ? 'Cancel subscription'
                      : 'Upgrade Account',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                ),
                leading: Image.asset(
                  'assets/images/vip.png',
                  height: 24,
                  width: 24,
                ),
              ),
              ListTile(
                dense: true,
                onTap: () {
                  push(context, new SettingsScreen(user: user));
                },
                title: Text(
                  'Settings',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                ),
                leading: Icon(
                  Icons.settings,
                  color: isDarkMode(context) ? Colors.white70 : Colors.black45,
                ),
              ),
              ListTile(
                dense: true,
                onTap: () {
                  push(context, new ContactUsScreen());
                },
                title: Text(
                  'Contact Us',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                ),
                leading: Icon(
                  Icons.call,
                  color: Colors.green,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0, horizontal: 24),
            child: ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: const BoxConstraints(minWidth: double.infinity),
              child: FlatButton(
                color: Colors.transparent,
                child: Text(
                  'Logout',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 16,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: isDarkMode(context) ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
                splashColor: isDarkMode(context)
                    ? Colors.grey[700]
                    : Colors.grey.shade200,
                onPressed: () async {
                  user.active = false;
                  user.lastOnlineTimestamp = Timestamp.now();
                  await FireStoreUtils.updateCurrentUser(user);
                  await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
                  MyAppState.currentUser = null;
                  pushAndRemoveUntil(context, AuthScreen(), false);
                },
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 12, bottom: 12),
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                    side: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey.shade200)),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }

  _onCameraClick() {
    final action = CupertinoActionSheet(
      message: Text(
        "Add profile picture",
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0),
      ),
      actions: <Widget>[
        CupertinoActionSheetAction(
          child: Text("Remove Picture"),
          isDestructiveAction: true,
          onPressed: () async {
            Navigator.pop(context);
            showProgress(context, 'Removing picture...', false);
            if (user.profilePictureURL.isNotEmpty)
              await _fireStoreUtils.deleteImage(user.profilePictureURL);
            user.profilePictureURL = '';
            await FireStoreUtils.updateCurrentUser(user);
            MyAppState.currentUser = user;
            hideProgress();
            setState(() {});
          },
        ),
        CupertinoActionSheetAction(
          child: Text("Choose from gallery"),
          onPressed: () async {
            Navigator.pop(context);
            PickedFile image =
                await _imagePicker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
            if (image != null) {
              await _imagePicked(File(image.path));
            }
            setState(() {});
          },
        ),
        CupertinoActionSheetAction(
          child: Text("Take a picture"),
          onPressed: () async {
            Navigator.pop(context);
            PickedFile image =
            await _imagePicker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
            if (image != null) {
              await _imagePicked(File(image.path));
            }
            setState(() {});
          },
        ),
      ],
      cancelButton: CupertinoActionSheetAction(
        child: Text("Cancel"),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        },
      ),
    );
    showCupertinoModalPopup(context: context, builder: (context) => action);
  }

  Future<void> _imagePicked(File image) async {
    showProgress(context, 'Uploading image...', false);
    user.profilePictureURL =
        await _fireStoreUtils.uploadUserImageToFireStorage(image, user.userID);
    await FireStoreUtils.updateCurrentUser(user);
    MyAppState.currentUser = user;
    hideProgress();
  }

  Widget _imageBuilder(String url) {
    bool isLastItem = url == null;

    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        isLastItem ? _pickAudio() : _viewOrDeleteImage(url);
      },
      child: Card(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          side: BorderSide.none,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
        ),
        color: Color(COLOR_PRIMARY),
        child: isLastItem
            ? Icon(
          Icons.music_note,
          size: 50,
          color: isDarkMode(context) ? Colors.black : Colors.white,
        )
            : ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
          child: CachedNetworkImage(
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            imageUrl:
            user.profilePictureURL == DEFAULT_AVATAR_URL ? '' : url,
            placeholder: (context, imageUrl) {
              return Icon(
                Icons.hourglass_empty,
                size: 75,
                color: isDarkMode(context) ? Colors.black : Colors.white,
              );
            },
            errorWidget: (context, imageUrl, error) {
              return Icon(
                Icons.error_outline,
                size: 75,
                color: isDarkMode(context) ? Colors.black : Colors.white,
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  List<Widget> _buildGridView() {
    _pages.clear();
    List<Widget> gridViewPages = [];
    var len = images.length;
    var size = 6;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i += size) {
      var end = (i + size < len) ? i + size : len;
      _pages.add(images.sublist(i, end));
    }
    _pages.forEach((elements) {
      gridViewPages.add(GridView.builder(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 16, left: 16),
          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
              crossAxisCount: 3,
              childAspectRatio: 1,
              crossAxisSpacing: 10,
              mainAxisSpacing: 10),
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => _imageBuilder(elements[index]),
          itemCount: elements.length,
          physics: BouncingScrollPhysics()));
    });
    return gridViewPages;
  }

  _viewOrDeleteImage(String url) {
    final action = CupertinoActionSheet(
      actions: <Widget>[
        CupertinoActionSheetAction(
          onPressed: () async {
            Navigator.pop(context);
            images.removeLast();
            images.remove(url);
            await _fireStoreUtils.deleteImage(url);
            user.photos = images;
            User newUser =
            await FireStoreUtils.updateCurrentUser(user);
            MyAppState.currentUser = newUser;
            user = newUser;
            images.add(null);
            setState(() {});
          },
          child: Text("Remove Picture"),
          isDestructiveAction: true,
        ),
        CupertinoActionSheetAction(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
            push(context, FullScreenImageViewer(imageUrl: url));
          },
          isDefaultAction: true,
          child: Text("View Picture"),
        ),
        CupertinoActionSheetAction(
          onPressed: () async {
            Navigator.pop(context);
            user.profilePictureURL = url;
            user = await FireStoreUtils.updateCurrentUser(user);
            setState(() {});
          },
          isDefaultAction: true,
          child: Text("Make Profile Picture"),
        )
      ],
      cancelButton: CupertinoActionSheetAction(
        child: Text("Cancel"),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        },
      ),
    );
    showCupertinoModalPopup(context: context, builder: (context) => action);
  }

  _pickImage() {
    final action = CupertinoActionSheet(
      message: Text(
        "Add picture",
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0),
      ),




      actions: <Widget>[
        CupertinoActionSheetAction(
          child: Text("Choose from Files"),
          isDefaultAction: false,
          onPressed: () async {
            Navigator.pop(context);
            PickedFile image =
            await _imagePicker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
            if (image != null) {
              Url imageUrl = await _fireStoreUtils.uploadChatImageToFireStorage(
                  File(image.path), context);
              images.removeLast();
              images.add(imageUrl.url);
              user.photos = images;
              User newUser =
              await FireStoreUtils.updateCurrentUser(user);
              MyAppState.currentUser = newUser;
              user = newUser;
              images.add(null);
              setState(() {});
            }
          },
        ),



        CupertinoActionSheetAction(
          child: Text("Take a picture"),
          isDestructiveAction: false,
          onPressed: () async {
            Navigator.pop(context);
            PickedFile image =
            await _imagePicker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
            if (image != null) {
              Url imageUrl = await _fireStoreUtils.uploadChatImageToFireStorage(
                  File(image.path), context);
              images.removeLast();
              images.add(imageUrl.url);
              user.photos = images;
              User newUser =
              await FireStoreUtils.updateCurrentUser(user);
              MyAppState.currentUser = newUser;
              user = newUser;
              images.add(null);
              setState(() {});
            }
          },
        )
      ],
      cancelButton: CupertinoActionSheetAction(
        child: Text("Cancel"),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        },
      ),
    );
    showCupertinoModalPopup(context: context, builder: (context) => action);
  }





//here is the code in question 
  _pickAudio() {

    final action = CupertinoActionSheet(
      message: Text(
        "Add Audio",
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0),
      ),




      actions: <Widget>[
        CupertinoActionSheetAction(

    child: Text("Choose from Files"),

          isDefaultAction: false,

    File file;// error is here
//on file choose button call this
    try {
    f = await FilePicker.getFile(
    type: FileType.audio,

    );
    setState(() {
    });
    }catch(e){
//handle exception
    }}

  onPressed:(){
  upload(file);
  }


  upload(File fil)async{


    String fileName = fil.path
        .split('/')
        .last;
    StorageReference firebaseStorageRef =
    FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('uploads/$fileName');
    StorageUploadTask uploadTask = firebaseStorageRef.putFile(fil);
    StorageTaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await uploadTask.onComplete;
    taskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(
            (value) {


        });
  }

        ),




      ],
      cancelButton: CupertinoActionSheetAction(
        child: Text("Cancel"),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        },
      ),
    );
    showCupertinoModalPopup(context: context, builder: (context) => action);
  }




  @override
  void dispose() {
    _currentPageNotifier.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }




}
```

any help would be amazing

thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Can you show us the push function  ' push(context, new ContactUsScreen()); '

Comment: @ahmetakil here you go: push(BuildContext context, Widget destination) {
  Navigator.of(context)
      .push(new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => destination));
}

Comment: What about  _fireStoreUtils.uploadUserImageToFireStorage() ? it might be using named parameters

Comment: @ahmetakil here you go:   Future<String> uploadUserImageToFireStorage(File image, String userID) async {
    StorageReference upload = storage.child("images/$userID.png");
    StorageUploadTask uploadTask = upload.putFile(image);
    var downloadUrl = await (await uploadTask.onComplete).ref.getDownloadURL();
    return downloadUrl.toString();
  }